# Australia visa: skilled employment of two jobs at the same time

Tags: visa, australia, employment, skilled-migration

For the Skilled visa (189 - Skilled Independant or 190 - Skilled Sponsor) does having 2 jobs at the same time count as twice the time length or not?

I am a software programmer, let's say I've been working 2 jobs (2 companies, both programming, 6 hours a day each) at the same time for the last 3 years. Is this counted as just 3 years due to time overlap? Or do they assess such work experience as 6 years? Please enlight me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be anything but 3 years in total, regardless of what or where the experience was acquired. Were you to indicate 6 years, your application could be seen as irregular, or deceptive, as the details wouldn't substantiate the numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Giorgio, is this written in any visa documents? If so, please let me know.